# Matrixmultiplication of 2 invertible Matrices is not commutative

Tags: matrices

I need to proof that the set of all invertible `n x n` Matrices with n > 1 is not commutative under multiplication? How could I do this? Thank you.

Comment: Your phrasing is incorrect. A set (at least, in my limited experience) cannot be described to be "commutative" or "non-commutative". What you meant to ask was whether matrix multiplication is commutative for invertible $n \times n$ matrices. Find a counterexample with $2 \times 2$ invertible matrices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We typically refer to the group of all invertible $n \times n$ matrices over the real numbers with the operation of multiplication as the General Linear Group, denoted $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$.  The question then becomes how to show that this group is not abelian.

For the case $n=2$, consider the matrices given by $$A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \quad \text{ and } \quad B = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}.$$
We have that $$ AB = \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$
and $$BA = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}.$$
Since $AB \neq BA$, we can conclude that matrices of size $2 \times 2$ do not commute and $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$ is not abelian.  To show this for $n \geq 3$, just extend these matrices by adding $1$'s along the main diagonal and $0$'s everywhere else and you have shown this for all $n \geq 2$.  Hope this helps!